# onMapReady Called Twice when using "extend AppCompactActivity" when first run

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity, appcompatactivity

Hello fellow developer,

I created a map using google map activity in android studio and my class extending AppCompactActivity because i want to use Toolbar. When running onMapReady called twice (i try it using Log.d) but when i am change AppCompactActivity to FragmentActivity it only called once.

Updated Code :

```
public class Maps extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {


Context context;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;

TextView eta, distance, tvfrom, tvto;
EditText txtTruck;
AutoCompleteTextView search;
Bitmap keraniMarker, truck, arrowup, puninar;
BitmapDescriptor bdfKerani = null, bdfTruck = null, bdfArrow = null, bdfPuninar = null;
CardView cardFind;
Button btnfind;
SwitchCompat swTraffic;

/////////////////////
static SwitchCompat swProgress;
TextView tvFilter;
ListView lvOrderTruck;
EditText txtSearch;

ArrayList<Order_Truck_SetGet> complete = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Order_Truck_SetGet> onGoing = new ArrayList<>();

String custCode = "nocust";
static String nopol_to_map = "all";
private Order_Truck_Adapter adapter_order_truck;

////////////////////

ArrayList<String> nop = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<LastLocationSetterGetter> lastloc = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<LatLng> livelatlng = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<startmark> arstart = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> project = new ArrayList<>();

String lokasi, nama, time, speed, statustitle;
TextView namadet, lokasidet, timedet, txtspeed, txtSPK, txtOMpils, txtOMccms, txtCust, txtDriver, txtRute, tvSiMbl, txtSiMbl;
ImageView call, sms, wa;
String telp = "+6281280688872";

LinearLayout llSpk, llOMpils, llOMccms, llCust, llDriver, llRute, llSiMbl;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private Dialog dashDialog, listOrderDialog;

int FLAG_START_DATE = 0;
int FLAG_END_DATE = 1;
int flag = -1;
int flag_menu = 0;
private long mLastClickTime = 0;

static final int LOCATION = 1;
static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL = 2;
static final int CALL_PHONE = 3;
static final int SEND_SMS = 4;
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;

Marker lastmark = null;
Marker startmark = null;
Marker track_arrow = null;

String pilih = Order_Truck.nopol_to_map;
String projectselect = "all";

LinearLayout llnopol, lldate, lllokasi;
ImageView nopol_arrow, date_arrow, lokasi_arrow;
ListView lvTruck;

ArrayList<Dashboard_Truck_SetGet> dastruck = new ArrayList<>();

private Dashboard_Truck_adapter adapter;
private DisplayMetrics metrics;

private boolean mAscendingOrder[] = {true, true, true};


String classname = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

Thread live = new Thread();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    //set for check permission
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS};
    if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }


    distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DISTANCE);
    eta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ETA);
    search = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.search);
    cardFind = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardFind);
    tvfrom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFrom);
    tvto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTo);
    btnfind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFind);
    swTraffic = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.swTraffic);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    cekOverlay();

    project.add("All Project");
    project.add("EXIM");

    //set logo for marker
    //option 1

    BitmapDrawable bitmap_kerani = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.truck);
    Bitmap kerani_ico = bitmap_kerani.getBitmap();
    keraniMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(kerani_ico, 100, 100, false);
    bdfKerani = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(keraniMarker);

    BitmapDrawable bitmap_puninar = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_puninar);
    Bitmap puninar_ico = bitmap_puninar.getBitmap();
    puninar = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(puninar_ico, 150, 150, false);
    bdfPuninar = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(puninar);

    BitmapDrawable bitmap_truck = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flat_truck);
    Bitmap truck_icon = bitmap_truck.getBitmap();
    truck = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(truck_icon, 70, 100, false);
    bdfTruck = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(truck);

    BitmapDrawable bitmap_arrow = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_arrow);
    Bitmap arrow_up = bitmap_arrow.getBitmap();
    arrowup = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(arrow_up, 70, 50, false);
    bdfArrow = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(arrowup);


    tvfrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setDate();
            flag = FLAG_START_DATE;
        }
    });

    tvto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setDate();
            flag = FLAG_END_DATE;
        }
    });

    btnfind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (tvfrom.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "From date must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (tvto.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "To date must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (pilih.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Police number must be choosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                getcarloc(pilih, projectselect);
            }
        }
    });

}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add  marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-3.503399, 112.423781), 4.0f));

    swTraffic.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                swTraffic.setText("Traffic ON  ");
                mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
                swTraffic.setText("Traffic OFF  ");
            }
        }
    });


    //GPS LAST POSITION
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            search.setText("");

        }
    });
    Log.d("pilihan", pilih + " ^.^");
    getNopol(projectselect);
    getcarloc(pilih, projectselect);


    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 15.0f));

            return false;
        }
    });

}

public void getcarloc(final String nopol, final String project) {
    if (flag_menu != 2) {
        mMap.clear();
        livelatlng.clear();
        lastloc.clear();
    }
    Log.d("PILIH2", nopol);

    Log.d("LIVESTATUS", String.valueOf(live.getState()));
    String url;
    showpDialog();
    if (flag_menu == 1) {
        url = Config.GET_LOCATION_HISTORICAL;
    } else {
        url = Config.GET_LAST_LOCATION;
    }

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.172172, 106.941581)).title("Puninar Jaya Cakung").snippet("Puninar Jaya Cakung").icon(bdfPuninar));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.128611, 106.941747)).title("Puninar Jaya Nagrak").snippet("Puninar Jaya Nagrak").icon(bdfPuninar));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.029199, 106.085906)).title("Puninar Jaya Cilegon").snippet("Puninar Jaya Cilegon").icon(bdfPuninar));


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("response", response);

            hidepDialog();
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("data");

                if (String.valueOf(jsonArray).equals("[]")) {
                    hidepDialog();
                    if (flag_menu == 1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is No Trip History From " + tvfrom.getText() + " Until " + tvto.getText() + " for " + pilih, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is No Data / Location For " + pilih, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {

                    Log.e("JSONARRAY", String.valueOf(jsonArray));

                    String vehicle_id = null,
                            vehicle_number = null;

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        //Get data last location or live tracking
                        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String position_id = obj.getString("position_id");
                        if (flag_menu != 1) {
                            vehicle_id = obj.getString("vehicle_id");
                            vehicle_number = obj.getString("vehicle_number");
                        }
                        String date_time = obj.getString("date_time");
                        Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("longitude")) / 10000000;
                        Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("latitude")) / 10000000;
                        String speed = obj.getString("speed");
                        String course = obj.getString("course");
                        String street_name = obj.getString("street_name");
                        String kecamatan = obj.getString("kecamatan");
                        String kabupaten = obj.getString("kabupaten");

                        if (flag_menu != 1) {
                            lastloc.add(new LastLocationSetterGetter(position_id, vehicle_id, vehicle_number,
                                    date_time, longitude, latitude, speed, course, street_name, kecamatan, kabupaten));
                        } else {
                            lastloc.add(new LastLocationSetterGetter(position_id, pilih,
                                    date_time, longitude, latitude, speed, course, street_name, kecamatan, kabupaten));
                        }


                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                        if (lastmark != null) {
                            lastmark.remove();
                        }

                        //Log.i("InfoSize", String.valueOf(lastloc.size()));

                        //create marker for live tracking
                        if (flag_menu != 0) {
                            livelatlng.add(latLng);
                            if (startmark == null) {
                                //create start marker
                                startmark = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Start").snippet(vehicle_number).icon(bdfKerani));
                                arstart.add(new startmark(street_name, kecamatan, kabupaten, vehicle_number, date_time, speed));
                            } else {
                                // create live tracking marker
                                lastmark = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(pilih).snippet(vehicle_number).icon(bdfTruck));
                                lastmark.setFlat(true);
                                lastmark.setRotation(Float.parseFloat(course));

                                if (lastloc.size() > 2) {
                                    track_arrow = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                            .position(new LatLng(lastloc.get(lastloc.size() - 2).getLatitude(), lastloc.get(lastloc.size() - 2).getLongitude()))
                                            .title(lastloc.get(lastloc.size() - 2).getPosition_id())
                                            .snippet(lastloc.get(lastloc.size() - 2).getVehicle_number())
                                            .icon(bdfArrow));
                                    track_arrow.setFlat(true);
                                    track_arrow.setRotation(Float.parseFloat(lastloc.get(lastloc.size() - 2).getCourse()));
                                }

                            }
                            if (livelatlng.size() > 1) {
                                //int ap22 =  getResources().getColor(R.color.fbutton_color_wet_asphalt);
                                int ap23 = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.fbutton_color_belize_hole);

                                Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                        .add(livelatlng.get(livelatlng.size() - 2), livelatlng.get(livelatlng.size() - 1))
                                        .width(10)
                                        .color(ap23));

                            }

                        } else {
                            //create marker for last location
                            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(vehicle_number).snippet(vehicle_number).icon(bdfKerani);
                            mMap.addMarker(marker);

                        }

                    }

                    Log.d("TOTALRECORD", String.valueOf(livelatlng.size()));

                    if (nopol != "all") {
                        Log.e("lastloc", String.valueOf(lastloc.size()));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lastloc.get(lastloc.size() - 1).getLatitude(), lastloc.get(lastloc.size() - 1).getLongitude()), 16.0f));
                        //cardFind.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {

                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-4.979218, 107.950524), 5.0f));
                    }

                    clickmap();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("ERRORCATCH", String.valueOf(e));
            }


        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            hidepDialog();
            Log.e("ERROR", String.valueOf(error));

            String message = null;
            if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                message = "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!";
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                message = "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!";
            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                message = "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.";
            }
            Log.e("VOLLEYERROR", message);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("prm_1", nopol);
            params.put("project", project);
            if (flag_menu == 1) {
                params.put("from", tvfrom.getText().toString());
                params.put("to", tvto.getText().toString());
            }

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            String credentials = "admin_it" + ":" + "admin123";
            String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            headers.put("Authorization", auth);

            return headers;
        }
    };

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}

public void getNopol(final String project) {
    Log.d("PILIHNOPOL", "NOPOL");
    //Get all police Number
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.GET_NOPOL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            nop.clear();
            if (flag_menu == 0) {
                nop.add("all");
            }

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("nopol");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String plat = obj.getString("vehicle_number").replace(" ", "");

                    nop.add(plat);
                }


                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Maps.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nop);
                search.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                search.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        pilih = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        mMap.clear();
                        startmark = null;
                        livelatlng.clear();
                        arstart.clear();
                        lastloc.clear();

                        if (flag_menu != 1) {
                            getcarloc(pilih, projectselect);
                        }


                        //Live Tracking selected
                        if (flag_menu == 2) {
                            if (live.getState().equals("TIMED_WAITING")) {
                                live.interrupt();
                                try {
                                    live.join();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }


                            live = new Thread() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        while (!isInterrupted()) {
                                            Thread.sleep(1000 * 76);
                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    getcarloc(pilih, projectselect);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            live.start();
                        }
                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("NORESPONSE", String.valueOf(error));
        }
    }

    ) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("project", project);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            String credentials = "admin_it" + ":" + "admin123";
            String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            headers.put("Authorization", auth);

            return headers;
        }
    };
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

}

This is my library

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your handling of the Google Map inside your `onCreate()` method seems slightly different than what I have used and seen.  Try using this code instead:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); // don't pass Maps.this

    // rest of your code here
}
```

My hunch is that somehow you were binding the listener twice, though I can't prove this without trying to duplicate your actual code locally.

Comment: is this what you mean ? 
MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(Maps.this);

MapsInitializer.initialize(this) is for this error (“IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized”) but it only happen to XIaoMi 3 (i using 3 device : emulator, samsung s5 and xiaomi 3g) and i already try to delete that MapsInitializer and error still occurred.

i will try your code first. If error still occurred, i will post my entire code
Thanks for answering :)

Comment: i already try what you suggest and error "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference"

i will edit my post to my full code

Comment: @BobySiwonhansamu Try changing your original code to use this line: `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)`.  _Don't_ pass `Map.this`

Comment: sorry i cant update my question to full right now. I already try that and still error like above. And after i analyze a little bit.

I put Log.d("Map","Ready"); in onMapReady and Log.d("Volley","Mark"); in my method to access database using volley. And actually my volley Called twice onMapReady but Log in onMapReady only called once. But it's only happen when start the activity. I will update my code immediately.

can you send your email, i will send my project using android studio to your email.